# IF... ELSE statement in R for text analysis

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I have a large dataframe that includes a description of the goods (about 11000 rows). I want to extract new variables (product type and product color) from the `Goods.Description`.

```
b <- data.frame(id = c('1','2', '3', '4'), Goods.Description = c("This green T-shirt can become...", "Stripes of unfaded denim at each side of this blue skirt make...", "Velvet's Brynna red top comes in a bohemian...", "The Riley blue jeans are Paige's take on..."), Jeans = c(0,0,0,0), T.Shirt = c(0,0,0,0), Skirt = c(0,0,0,0), Top = c(0,0,0,0), Color = c(0,0,0,0))
```

Dataframe:

```
  id                                                Goods.Description Jeans T.Shirt Skirt Top Color
1  1                                 This green T-shirt can become...     0       0     0   0     0
2  2 Stripes of unfaded denim at each side of this blue skirt make...     0       0     0   0     0
3  3                   Velvet's Brynna red top comes in a bohemian...     0       0     0   0     0
4  4                      The Riley blue jeans are Paige's take on...     0       0     0   0     0
```

For example,
If `Goods.Description` contains the word "T-shirt", then put 1 in `T.Shirt`, else 0.

If `Goods.Description` contains the word "jeans", then put 1 in `Jeans`, else 0.

If `Goods.Description` contains the word "skirt", then put 1 in `Skirt`, else 0.

If `Goods.Description` contains the word "top", then put 1 in `Top`, else 0.

If `Goods.Description` contains the word "green", then put `green` in `Color`, else 0.

If `Goods.Description` contains the word "blue", then put `blue` in `Color`, else 0.

and so on

After:

```
  id                                                Goods.Description Jeans T.Shirt Skirt Top Color
1  1                                 This green T-shirt can become...     0       1     0   0 green
2  2 Stripes of unfaded denim at each side of this blue skirt make...     0       0     1   0  blue
3  3                   Velvet's Brynna red top comes in a bohemian...     0       0     0   1   red
4  4                      The Riley blue jeans are Paige's take on...     1       0     0   0  blue
```

I do not know what the code should be. Please, help me.

Comment: The title doesn't match the question. You are not asking about creating new variables, by assignment based on regex.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a minimal reproducible example as code (also containing R code to create the data table with your example data to help us save time to provide an answer).

Comment: @RYoda, ok! I add R code to create dataframe.

Comment: I think storing the colors as string in one column is OK, but storing a zero (0) into the same column in case of no matches causing the zero to be coerced into a string. How about creating a separate color indicator column for each color containing 1 or 0?

Comment: @RYoda, great idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

b <- data.frame(id = c('1','2', '3', '4'), Goods.Description = c("This green T-shirt can become...", "Stripes of unfaded denim at each side of this blue skirt make...", "Velvet's Brynna red top comes in a bohemian...", "The Riley blue jeans are Paige's take on..."), Jeans = c(0,0,0,0), T.Shirt = c(0,0,0,0), Skirt = c(0,0,0,0), Top = c(0,0,0,0), Color = c(0,0,0,0))
str(b)

setDT(b) # convert to data.table for better performance...

b[, Jeans := as.integer(grepl("jeans", Goods.Description, fixed = TRUE))]
b[, Skirt := as.integer(grepl("skirt", Goods.Description, fixed = TRUE))]
# etc. for each keyword

# Collect the colors in the "Color" target column

# initialize with empty string instead of zero (implicitly converting the col class to character)
b[, Color := NULL]
b[, Color := ""]
for (a.color in c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"))
  b[grepl(a.color, Goods.Description, fixed = TRUE), Color := paste(Color, a.color)] # paste color names to keep all colors

b
```

results in

```
   id                                                Goods.Description Jeans T.Shirt Skirt Top  Color
1:  1                                 This green T-shirt can become...     0       0     0   0  green
2:  2 Stripes of unfaded denim at each side of this blue skirt make...     0       0     1   0   blue
3:  3                   Velvet's Brynna red top comes in a bohemian...     0       0     0   0    red
4:  4                      The Riley blue jeans are Paige's take on...     1       0     0   0   blue
```

Comment: Since you used for loop, it would be natural to use set() to update values to the column under iteration here for efficiency reasons. Please read ?':=' for more info.

Comment: @Sathish Thx for the tip! Honestly I did never understand when `set` is the right solution to make it faster. The help says *"[avoids] overhead to check the existence and type of arguments"* but since I am iterating of a few columns only in this solution (and not over all rows which are much more normally) I cannot recognize how `set` could save much time here.

Comment: @RYoda your answer is fine, no issues. I was telling about `set()` because it will reduce the overhead of updating many columns inside `[` using `:=`. In your case, there is only one column and you are iterating over a character vector.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this by extracting the 'color' and specific words from the column names

```
library(stringr)
b$Color <- str_extract(b$Goods.Description, 'green|blue|red|blue')
v1 <- toupper(sub(".", "-", names(b)[3:6], fixed = TRUE))
b[3:6][cbind(1:nrow(b), match(v1, 
      str_extract(toupper(b$Goods.Description), paste(v1, collapse="|"))))] <- 1

b
#   id                                                Goods.Description Jeans T.Shirt Skirt Top Color
#1  1                                 This green T-shirt can become...     0       0     0   1 green
#2  2 Stripes of unfaded denim at each side of this blue skirt make...     1       0     0   0  blue
#3  3                   Velvet's Brynna red top comes in a bohemian...     0       1     0   0   red
#4  4                      The Riley blue jeans are Paige's take on...     0       0     1   0  blue
```